# How a client maintains a list of guard nodes, from among hundreds of guard nodes, for creating a circuit?

Tags: circuit, guard

It is said that a client maintains a list of guard nodes for certain time for making a circuit. I want to know how many number of guard nodes they make in a list? How often they change these guard nodes and how do they maintain a list from hundred of nodes available?

Answer (score 2):

You can find your EntryGuards in your data directory. If you are using the Tor Browser Bundle, you have the list in `Data/Tor/state`. In other cases there will be a `.tor` directory in your home directory or similar.

Currently Tor selects 3 EntryGuards per default. This setting may however be changed using [NumEntryGuards](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#NumEntryGuards). There is another option that is called GuardLifetime. According to the manual it is based of what the network consensus is.

Comment: I found my entry guards in .tor/state. But I want to know how these 3 entry guards are listed for me from among the available total entry guards?